# RediScala : [NettyTransport(akka://default)] When connect to redis

Tags: scala, rediscala

I am very new to scala programming language and i am getting

```
[ERROR] [06/26/2016 14:52:36.448] [default-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-5] [NettyTransport(akka://default)] failed to bind to /127.0.0.1:16000, shutting down Netty transport

[ERROR] [06/26/2016 14:52:36.458] [ForkJoinPool-4-worker-7] [akka.remote.Remoting] Remoting error: [Startup failed] [
akka.remote.RemoteTransportException: Startup failed
```

Whenever i connect to redis using **rediscala**

Following is the code i am using to get the redis connection

```
import redis.RedisClient
import scala.concurrent.{Future, Await}
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object RedisConnection {
  implicit val akkaSystem = akka.actor.ActorSystem()

  def connect(): RedisClient = {
    RedisClient("localhost", 6379)
  }

  def close(): Unit = {
    akkaSystem.terminate()
  }
}
```

Please help me i have wasted a lot of time to figure the problem

Comment: Maybe the port `16000` is used.

Comment: Yeah this is used by 

```  remote {
   enabled-transports =  ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 16000
    }```

Actually i am not getting how can create a new actor system on another port

Comment: If you want to run 2 actor systems on one pc and have different port I am not sure but you probably need to create those systems using a different configuration that would contain a dirrerent port. Take look at http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/remoting.html

Comment: Thanks. I followed that and it worked fine.. Somewhere i read creating two actor systems are expensive. Is there any way i can used the actor system which i was using for my application for redis too ??

Comment: Hard to tell from the given code. Why are you using 2 systems? Who and why creates them?

Comment: So  i create a system for actors i want to create and one system is required by rediscala to connect

Comment: Well, if you control creation of actor systems, why don't you create just one and pass it to both places that use it.